# Get Visual Studio web developer back?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer

I only installed C# when I installed visual studio due to EXTREMELY low disk space. I need to get the 'Webdeveloper' feature back but I can not find anything? Anyone go any idea on how to do this without reinstalling?

On visual studio 2010

Comment: what do you think??  is it possible to install it without running repair or reinstall setup of Visual studio???

Comment: Visual studio is just a shell, all the languages are just additional plugins. It is completely possible....

Comment: Run the visual studio setup, again, and select what you wish to add.